# Start new activity from recyclerview with firebase datatabase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am using a custom recyclerview to populate data from my firebase database. I have been able to do that successfully, but now I am struggling with starting a new activity when an item is clicked. I am getting a null pointer error when i click an item. I am trying to retrieve the pushID of the item and use it to start its detail activity. This is my code

MY ADAPTER

```
public class SearchResultsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchResultsAdapter.SearchViewHolder> {


    Context context;
    String downloadUrl;

    String post_key;
    ArrayList<Search1> mSearchList = new ArrayList<Search1>();
    private ItemClickListener mItemClickListener;


    private DatabaseReference databaseReference15;
    //Constructor of this class
    public SearchResultsAdapter(ArrayList<Search1> mSearchList,Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        //Getting all superheroes
        this.mSearchList = mSearchList;
    }

    @Override
    public SearchViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.searchrow, parent, false);
        SearchViewHolder searchViewHolder = new SearchViewHolder(itemView, mItemClickListener);
        return searchViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SearchViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {

        final Context context = viewHolder.downloadUrls.getContext();

        //Showing data on the views
        final Search1 c = mSearchList.get(position);
        post_key = c.getKey();
        viewHolder.uzername.setText(c.getUsername());
        Picasso.with(context).load(c.downloadUrl).into(viewHolder.downloadUrls);
        databaseReference15 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("UG").child("UzersAll");
       viewHolder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                databaseReference15.child(post_key).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        String searched = (String) dataSnapshot.child("username").getValue();
                        String halls = (String) dataSnapshot.child("halls").getValue();
                        Intent SearchIntent = new Intent(context, SearchView1.class);
                        SearchIntent.putExtra("key", post_key);
                        SearchIntent.putExtra("username", searched);
                        SearchIntent.putExtra("halls", halls);

                        context.startActivity(SearchIntent);


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Check Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });


    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mSearchList.size();
    }




    public class SearchViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener  {
        //Views

        public TextView uzername;
        public CircularImageView downloadUrls;
        private ItemClickListener mItemClickListener;


        Context context;
      //  ArrayList<Search1> mSearchList = new ArrayList<Search1> ();

        //Initializing Views
        public SearchViewHolder(View itemView,ItemClickListener itemClickListener ) {
            super(itemView);
            context = itemView.getContext();
            this.mItemClickListener = itemClickListener;
           // this.context = context;
            //this.mSearchList = mSearchList;

             uzername = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.uzername);
            downloadUrls = (CircularImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.downloadUrls);
        //    itemView.setClickable(true);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);


        }

        public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener){
            this.mItemClickListener = itemClickListener ;
        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          //  int position = getAdapterPosition();
            //Search1 mSearchList = this.mSearchList.get(position);
          //  post_key = mSearchList.getKey();
            if(mItemClickListener != null){
                mItemClickListener.onClick(v,getAdapterPosition());
            }


        }
    }


}
```

MY ACTIVITY

```
public class SearchResultsTest  extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView mSearchlist;

    private DatabaseReference databaseReference1, databaseReference2;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    Query query;
    String user_key;
    String halls;
    String lastKnownKey;
    private ArrayList<Search1> searchList = new ArrayList<>();
    private LinearLayoutManager mlinearLayout;
    private SearchResultsAdapter mAdapter;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout mRefreshLayout;
    private static final int TOTAL_ITEMS_TO_LOAD = 2;
    private int mCurrentPage = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.searchlist);

        Intent SearchIntent = getIntent();
        halls = SearchIntent.getStringExtra("halls");
        //    final String sex = SearchIntent.getStringExtra("sex");

        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar3);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(halls);

        mAdapter = new SearchResultsAdapter(searchList,this);

        mSearchlist = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.searchlist);
        mlinearLayout = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe);

        mSearchlist.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mSearchlist.setLayoutManager(mlinearLayout);
        // mSearchlist.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mSearchlist.swapAdapter(mAdapter, true);

        //setAdapter(adapter)


        databaseReference1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("UG").child("UzersH");
        databaseReference2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("UG").child("Users1");

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        final String user_id = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        loadResults();

       /* mSearchlist.addOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(mlinearLayout) {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore(int current_page) {
                mCurrentPage++;
               searchList.clear();// when we have reached end of RecyclerView this event fired
                loadResults();
            }
        });*/

        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading Please Wait...");
        mProgressDialog.show();

       /* mRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener(){
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                mCurrentPage++;
                searchList.clear();// when we have reached end of RecyclerView this event fired
                loadResults();
            }



        });*/
        mRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                mCurrentPage++;
                searchList.clear();// when we have reached end of RecyclerView this event fired
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();// when we have reached end of RecyclerView this event fired

                loadResults();
            }
        });



    }


    private void loadResults() {

        // Query query = databaseReference1.child(halls);
       /* Query query = databaseReference1.child(halls).orderByChild("ts").limitToFirst(mCurrentPage * TOTAL_ITEMS_TO_LOAD);
        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(!dataSnapshot.hasChildren()){

                    mCurrentPage--;
                }

                for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Search1 search = data.getValue(Search1.class);
                    searchList.add(search);
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();

                }
               *//* Search1 search = dataSnapshot.getValue(Search1.class);
                searchList.add(search);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();*//*


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });*/



    // .startAt(mCurrentPage*TOTAL_ITEMS_TO_LOAD);;
    //.startAt(2).orderByChild("ts");
    //.limitToFirst(TOTAL_ITEMS_TO_LOAD);
    //.startAt(mCurrentPage*TOTAL_ITEMS_TO_LOAD);


        Query query = databaseReference1.child(halls).orderByChild("ts").limitToFirst(mCurrentPage * TOTAL_ITEMS_TO_LOAD);
        query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                if (!dataSnapshot.hasChildren()){


                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();

                }
                Search1 search = dataSnapshot.getValue(Search1.class);
                searchList.add(search);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                mSearchlist.scrollToPosition(searchList.size()-1);
                mRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

                mProgressDialog.dismiss();

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
}


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                // todo: goto back activity from here

                /*Intent intent = new Intent(ViewProfile.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);*/
                finish();
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

LOG CAT ERROR

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: dev.mintz.minzter, PID: 4703
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()
                      at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.child(Unknown Source)
                      at dev.mintz.minzter.SearchResultsAdapter$1.onClick(SearchResultsAdapter.java:73)
                      at dev.mintz.minzter.SearchResultsAdapter$SearchViewHolder.onClick(SearchResultsAdapter.java:158)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: This line too mItemClickListener.onClick(v,getAdapterPosition()); @JuanCruzSoler

Answer (score 0):

This line `post_key = c.getKey();` assigns a null value.
Then when you call `databaseReference15.child(post_key)` it says that null is not an allowed value.

Look the values in your variable `mSearchList` to see why it happens.

Comment: This line too mItemClickListener.onClick(v,getAdapterPosition());